# Mockery cannot create a partial mock with Eloquent Model fill method

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5, mockery

I'm trying to test a Laravel api.
When I try to create a partial mock with the Eloquent Model fill method, phpunit throws an error.

Code

```
$mock = m::mock('App\User', [])->makePartial();
$mock->shouldReceive('fill')->once()->andReturn('ok');
$result = $mock->fill([]);
var_dump($result);
```

Error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function __call() on a non-object
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException' with message 'Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable.
```

I really don't know if this either a Eloquent bug, or a Mockery error.

Notes:

I temporarily solved this problem using Model::update method instead of Model::fill and then Model::save, but I still want to know how to mock the fill method.

Links

http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fill

Answer (score 2):

I think the mock object is created but without this method. You will need to define an expectation for the `fill()` method to dictate her mocked behaviour. like:

```
$mock->shouldReceive('fill')->once()->andReturn('ok');
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Exactly, using [methodName] means that only that method should be mocked.

Comment: This answer is almost completely right. If I add that line it still throws the same error, but you helped to find the real problem. The real problem is the following, the Model constructor calls the fill function, and this occurs before adding the expectation. So, I was looking how to solve this and I found that I need to create a partial mock, but now it throws another error.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a passive partial mock as:

```
$mock = m::mock('Model')->makePartial();
$mock->shouldReceive("fill")->once()->andReturn("ok");
```

In passive partial, all methods will simply defer to the parent class original methods unless a method call matches a known expectation. And it will skip the call of the unexpected  `fill` method in Model constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I did it, but now it throws me another error, and I'm still looking for how to mock the fill method.

Comment: It throws the following errors: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function __call() on a non-object
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException' with message 'Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable.